# How do you make the radio button text be clickable too?

Tags: html

I have the following code below:

```
 <div class="customisation-color-options">
    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}

    <div class="customisation-custom-color radio">
        <label for="default-color">
            <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio not_unifrom" name="{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" value="{$id_attribute}" {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} checked="checked"{/if} />
            <span>
            {if $id_attribute == 25}
                Utilisez la couleur par défaut
            {else}
                {$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
            {/if}   

            </span>
        </label>
        {if $id_attribute == 26}
        <input type='text' id="custom-color-picker" class="not_unifrom"/>
        {/if}
    </div>  

    {/foreach}
 </div>
```

I want to make the text "Utilisez la couleur par défaut" and "Choisissez votre couleur" clikable just like the radio button. And i also need it to change radio button once the color picker is activated by click.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` attribute.

A label without a `for` attribute is the label for the form control inside it.

A label with one is the label for the element with the matching ID … and you don't have an element with a matching ID.